# Add custom information to HockeyApp crash report

Tags: ios, hockeyapp

I integrated my iOS app with HockeyApp platform. Everything works properly, but I need to add some extra information, like texts from NSLog, to crash reports. It is possible? I don't want to use external frameworks (NSLogger, CocoaLumberjack), Databases, Servers, Webapis. I want to store everything information about crash in one place - HockeyApp. Did someone has problem like that or/and develop some solution? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What custom information? We need examples to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like what you are looking for:

> 1. Setup the logging framework of choice
> 2. Implement `[BITCrashManagerDelegate applicationLogForCrashManager:]`
> 3. Return the log data

See the [HockeyApp documentation](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x/how-to-add-application-specific-log-data-on-ios)